# Jest "testRegex" throws "Unexpected token . in JSON"

Tags: jestjs

I'm using jest to unit test my server and when I set the "testRegex" on my package.json to be

```
"testRegex": "(/test/.*|(\.|/)test)\.js$"
```

I get this error: Unexpected token . in JSON

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"\."` is invalid escape character in JSON. You need to escape the backslash:

```json
"testRegex": "(/test/.*|(\\.|/)test)\\.js$"
```